# Is an iPhone 5C suitable for Development in 2017?

Tags: development, iphone

I am working on a Unity game, and I cannot afford to buy both an iPhone 7, and my main phone that I am upgrading to (Galaxy S8), nor can I afford to buy a Mac right now. Would developing on a Virtual Machine running on a Windows Laptop, along with using an iPhone 5C to test and debug on be a good idea? I have heard some problems with developing with the 5C due to the 32 bit processor, but I do not know if that would also apply to games.

Comment: a VM on Windows would make this off-topic, as it's against Apple's EULA. An iPhone 5C will be pretty much useless after iOS 11 is released, as there is no more 32-bit support.

Comment: So since there is no 32 bit support, does that bassicslly mean that the 5 and 5C cannot download any newer apps anymore (example: My game or Monument Valley 2)

Comment: idk, to be honest - but if you can't test against the current OS, you can't submit a new app

Comment: @Tetsujin Would the emulator be a suitable way to test then? (Problem is: It's a game that requires a lot of touch input)

Comment: You'd be faking an emu inside a VM on a win lappy... your chances of success are very slim indeed.

Comment: @MJonesDev: Your iPhone 5C lacks a 64-bit processor, and so won't run iOS 11. Apps that will run on iOS 10 *and* included 32-bit code when they were uploaded should still be installable. However, new versions for iOS 11 may not include 32-bit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Virtual Machine running on a Windows Laptop"**

Good luck with that one. There is basically no 3D acceleration in any VM for Windows running macOS currently available. Linux is able to achieve this in some cases (KVM + spare macOS-supported PCIe GPU), but it has its own set of different limitations that may break the deal for you. And it's also banned by macOS's EULA.

**"along with using an iPhone 5C to test and debug"**

iOS 11 will make the 5C obsolete, as well as any and all 32-bit apps, so you won't be able to do much with a 5C. (Unless you're developing for less than 3 months ;) )

**"I do not know if that would also apply to games."**

It would, and even more so. There are many technical limitations with 32-bit apps that 64-bit OSes do not have, notably the restriction to no more than 4GB of RAM. It is relatively safe to assume that Apple ended 32-bit app support because the iPad Pros push right into that 4GB limit, and there can only be more and more RAM installed into iOS devices.

**What would I do?**

If you're going solo, make your current laptop a Hackintosh (it breaks the EULA but it's your best option for now) and run all your apps in the Simulator or on friends' devices. I say this for two reasons:

1. If you don't make enough money to buy a Mac (~$1000+), you likely aren't a very big company and Apple will never bother to sue you.
2. If you are a big enough company that Apple notices that you are using a Hackintosh, you probably have enough money for a **few** Macs by now, so you can buy one.

Better yet, go develop for a company that has money for you. Then you can earn money to buy your own devices for your own projects and future jobs. Besides, you can probably ask for company funding for a Mac (probably a MacBook Pro 13 Fn, but it's better than nothing) straight-away.